# What is the best practice to create pointer in loop and deallocate memory

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, pointers, memory

My knowledge in C++ is not so good so please, be nice :).

**My question is general about way of coding. Even if my example below focus on QGraphicsScene, the same problem is true with QTableItem object or any object using pointers.**

I am trying to create pointers in a loop and I am facing an obvious difficulty.
Each time I pass in my loop, I am creating a new space in the memory without releasing it, leading to memory leaks. I do not know what is the best practice to write this kind of code.
I am giving you below a piece of code as example that maybe you could help me to improve so that I will be able to understand.

```
void MainWindows::function(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        QGraphicsScene *sceneP =  new QGraphicsScene();
        QPixmap pixmapP(QString::fromStdString("/home/xyz/"+std::to_string(i)+".png"));
        sceneP->addPixmap(pixmapP);
        ui->graph->setScene(sceneP);
        ui->graph->show();
    }
}
```

The example is very simple but what I want here is to charge in my application the pictures located at /home/xyz/1.png, /home/xyz/2.png ...etc.
Obviously, these pictures are loaded in the sceneP and then at the second iteration, they are lost in memory.
My question is the following:
Do you know a simple way to code this function without losing anything in memory ?
Thank you very much

Comment: qt does manage objects for you (under certain circumstances, dont know much qt either). This is more about qt memory managment rather than c++

Comment: You are not setting the parent on QGraphicsScene(). For example `QGraphicsScene *sceneP =  new QGraphicsScene(this);`

Comment: After setting the parent you can do auto children = findChildren<QGraphicsScene*>(); to get a list of all of the existing `QGraphicsScene` objects.

Comment: You are both right, thx I did edition of my question

Comment: Declare an array of 10 pointers outside of the loop, in the scope that will use them, then ensure the pointers are deleted when no longer required.

Comment: adding the `()` does not change much. Anyhow, please dont change your question according to answers/comments you get. The question should have your broken code, fixes should go into answers

Comment: If `setScene` does not have influence on ownership - why not just create the scene object on the stack like the `QPixmap` directly afterwards? Before leaving the function, unsetting (by setting a nullptr?) the scene in `ui->graph` again avoids the dangling pointer.

Comment: @Aconcagua, when I do this, the soft is giving a segmentation fault

Comment: @froz You might need to unset the scene before it is destroyed. Did you try?

Comment: @Aconcagua, I tried something different:
    `QGraphicsScene sceneP;
    QPixmap pixmapP(QString::fromStdString("/home/xyz/"+std::to_string(i)+".png"));
    sceneP.addPixmap(pixmapP);
    ui->graph->setScene(&sceneP);`
However scene is deleted immediately after so the picture does not apear

Comment: @drescherjm, what will be the type of children? How can I iterate over these scenes?

Comment: @froz My fault - assumed show would not return until scene is closed, missing that this is not Qt behaviour...

Comment: But can the view have more than one scene at once? If not, you'd only be showing the last scene loaded anyway...

Comment: Yes I am only showing the last scene but all the previous stay in memory and it increases fast with heavy pictures :)

Comment: But why do you load all of them if you only show one anyway? That's just wasting CPU and RAM...

Comment: Might be the better option to create the scene once (with parent!), set it in graph once, too (both in constructor?) and then just add and [remove](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem) the pixmap.

Comment: Yes my question is probably not well asked... I did a simplified piece of code. In fact, the real function loads an image depending on a QComboBox. So, I get the same situation. When I change the value of the qcombobox, a new QGraphicsScene is created and lost in memory. I just wanted to give a general and simple function.

Comment: OK, you can get the object back via `scene()` and delete it before assigning a new one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt provides its own memory management - why not profit from?

You could create the scene object only once and then just exchange the pixmaps – similar to below (be aware that this is not tested, just for giving you the idea):

```
class MainWindows
{
    QGraphicsItem* pixmap; // raw pointer: I assume ownership remains at the view
                           // object (documentation is not explicit about...), though
                           // if not: use std::unique_ptr instead...
    MainWindows(...)
        : // ...
          pixmap(nullptr)
    {
        ui->graph->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    }
};

void MainWindows::function()
{
    if(this->pixmap)
    {
        ui->graph->scene()->removeItem(pixmap);
    }

    // according to comment:
    unsigned int n = ...; // select from combo box

    QPixmap pixmapP(QString("/home/xyz/%1.png").arg(n)); // a bit more convenient
    this->pixmap = ui->graph->scene()->addPixmap(pixmapP);
    ui->graph->show();
}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer re-creating the scene object each time:

```
QGraphicsScene* sceneP = new QGraphicsScene();
QPixmap pixmapP(...);
sceneP->addPixmap(pixmapP);

// delete the old one
// (delete is robust against nullptr, so no check needed...)
delete ui->graph->scene(); // now dangling, but you replace it anyway

ui->graph->setScene(sceneP);
ui->graph->show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Can I do something similar when I declare a new QTableWidgetItem as a pointer ? Arf maybe it s not important because they dont load a lot the memory

Comment: As long as memory management is the same, yes. If the container the items are set into takes ownership of, you need to prevent double deletion!